# numpy.rint not working as expected

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the cause of this result:

```
import numpy
result1 = numpy.rint(1.5)
result2 = numpy.rint(6.5)
print result
```

The output:

```
result1-> 2
result2-> 6
```

This is odd: *result1* is correct but I *result2* is not (It has to be 7 because *rint* rounds any float to [the *nearest* integer](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rint.html)).

Any idea? (THANKS!)

Comment: isn't 6 equally as near as 7?

Comment: Floats are neither real numbers nor rational numbers. Make sure 6.5 is actually 6 plus one half, not 6.499999999999 or something.

Comment: Note that `np.round(1.5) == np.round(2.5)`, due to floating point limitations

Comment: ^^ That is not because of floating point limitations - it is customary to round to the even number when the number being rounded lies exactly midway between two integers.

Comment: OK, I should have said due to floating point weirdness

Comment: @wim yati is saying the properties of floating point numbers are inconsequential, because `round` is defined to break ties by favoring even numbers. That works for platonic real numbers as well as it does for floats.

Comment: interesting that `np.round` differs from python `round` in this respect.

Comment: @delnan Floats *are* rational numbers, with the constraint that their denominators can only be powers of two. Python's `as_integer_ratio()` method on floats will even tell you which fraction it is (for example, 0.1 is represented as the 3602879701896397/36028797018963968 fraction. In the case of 6.5, however, the underlying rational is exactly the one you'd expect - 13/2.

Comment: @user4815162342  that's very cool, I've never noticed that method on floats before!

Comment: @user4815162342 They are a *subset* of the rational numbers. A subset with almost none of the properties people expect, most of all not being able to exactly represent most fractions with powers of ten denominators (i.e. decimals). But yes, 6.5 turns out to work, that was a knee jerk response.

Comment: @delnan Of course. The point is that they can be reasoned about as rational numbers (with the additional constraint), they're not magically erroneous or scary as they are sometimes presented, starting with the best intentions of warning programmers of pitfalls in floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @user4815162342 That they won't magically fail in is a very good point, though I'm not sure whether thinking of them as rationals-with-restrictions of the best way of formally approaching their use (the papers I read seem to assume reals and keep track of errors along the way, or refer to IEEE 754 to show that there are no errors). However, I've come to the conclusion that putting too little trust in floats is better than too much, especially with some compilers and platforms (in C and friends, not so much Python) deviating from IEEE 754 when you least expect it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [numpy's documentation on `numpy.around`, equivalent to `numpy.round`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around), which supposedly also is relevant for `numpy.rint`:

> For values exactly halfway between rounded decimal values, Numpy
>   rounds to the nearest even value. Thus 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5
>   and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc. Results may also be surprising due to the
>   inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point
>   standard [R9] and errors introduced when scaling by powers of ten.

Also relevant: While for large numbers there might be representation errors, for small values half integers are exactly representable in binary-base floating points, in particular `1.5` and `6.5` are exactly representable in standard single-precision floats. Without the preference for either odd, even, lower, upper integers or any other scheme one would have undefined behaviour here.

As @wim points out in the comments the behaviour of Python's build-in `round` is different. It rounds away from zero: It prefers upper integers for positive inputs and lower integers for negative inputs. (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the rule of the thumb - when you have a float midway between two integers, like 1.5 lies midway between 1 and 2 and since both choices are equally good, we prefer rounding to the even number(which is 2 in this case) and for 6.5, which lies midway between 6 and 7, 6 is the closest even number.